# Iterating a Dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

When I try to iterate this Dictionary, it only prints out twice the customer with "2222" as the key. I have no idea why this is happening. In the past I tried to use different variables for the customer c1 and c2 (instead of just c) but that defeated the purpose of using a for loop to print the dictionary.

```
Dict = {}
c = Customer.Customer("1111","Jake","Main St","Happy Valley","CA","96687","8976098765")
Dict[c.getCNumber()] = c
print(Dict[c.getCNumber()].getCNumber())
c = Customer.Customer("2222","Paul","3342 CherrySt","Seatle","WA","98673","9646745678")
Dict[c.getCNumber()] = c
print(Dict[c.getCNumber()].getCNumber())

for key in Dict.keys():
  print("***Customer***")
  print("Customer Number: " + c.getCNumber)
```

This prints:

```
***Customer***
Customer Number: 2222
***Customer***
Customer Number: 2222
```

How do I get it to iterate and have customer 1111 first, then customer 2222 second?

Comment: `dict`s are **not** ordered. You must first copy the elements into a list, sort the list and output the result. Besides, in your output there is no `1111`.

Comment: Your code is a bit jumbled up; you may want to verify that it is what you intended to write. Also, show `Customer.Customer`.

Comment: The issue isn't the order, it is iterating through the dict and being able to print each customer's information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what you told your loop to do: traverse a keyset, **and for every key in dictionary print a number of c variable**. Change your loop like so:

```
for key in Dict.keys():
   print("***Customer***")
   print("Customer Number: " + Dict[key].getCNumber())
```

I believe that `getCNumber` is method, not a variable, so you need to call it - add a couple of braces after the method name, as I've shown above.
Also, it's generally a better idea to stick to python naming conventions and start the names of your variables from the lower-case letters - so you should rename the `Dict` variable to something like `dict`.
If you need to traverse the keys of your dictionary in the sorted order, you can write the `for` loop like so:

```
for key in sorted(dict.keys()):
```

Comment: It won't be ordered as he asked, he need to use OrderedDict

Comment: That's exactly why i wrote the comment, `1111 first, then customer 2222 second` but i see at your edit that you added `sorted()` so +1 for that :)

Comment: Thank you! I just started learning Python a few days ago. This was my first post. This helped out a ton!

Answer (score 1):

```
for key in Map.keys():
```

You were calling your dict `Dict` before. If what you've posted is what you actually ran, then this is iterating over an entirely unrelated dict.

```
  print("Customer Number: " + c.getCNumber)
```

You refer to `c` here, rather than anything related to `key`. `c` is still the last customer you created. If `Map` contains two keys, this will print `c`'s information twice. (Actually, since the function call parentheses are missing, it might print something along the lines of `<bound method object at...>`.)

Answer (score 1):

`.keys` isn't required.

`Python 2`

```
In [127]: d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

In [128]: for key in d:
.....:     print(key)
.....:
a
b
```

`Python 3`

```
In [34]: d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

In [35]: for key in d:
....:     print(key)
....:
a
b
```

Looping over dict gives `key`.